# Apache POI java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My code is below:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

 public class ExcelRead{

     public static void main(String[] args){
        String docName = "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\excelExample.xlsx";
        try{
            InputStream xlsxDoc = new FileInputStream(docName);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsxDoc);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());          
        }
        catch(Exception e){  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

And the error code I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(ILjava/lang/Object;)V
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:313)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:131)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:559)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:112)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:83)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:128)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart.<init>(ZipPackagePart.java:78)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:243)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:673)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:274)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:258)
at AristocratProject_1.ExcelRead.main
```

The dependencies for Apache that I have added to my netbeans library are:

```
poi-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-3.11.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

And from here I pretty much have no idea what to do. Can anyone tell me if my code is wrong or what other dependencies I need?

Comment: `poi-3.17.jar` `poi-ooxml-3.11.jar`  That immediately stands out as a problem to me.

Comment: ok, except literally every stackexchange page says to have these

Comment: I'm sure they mention to have matching versions of these jars.

Comment: do you mean the versions have to be matching? In that case then apache is just trash for not packaging everything correctly

Comment: While I understand your frustration with your error, I'm not sure how you wound up with two different version of jars that _are_ packaged together.  Please see the [download page](https://poi.apache.org/download.html).

Comment: how do I fix this? Do I downgrade poi to 3.11?

Comment: Alright ill redownload and see because i extracted my files from the binary files, and it came with 3.17 poi and 3.11 ooxml

Comment: ok i got 3.17 ooxml and now im getting another error. Ill just make a new post for that. I appreciate your help and sorrfy for frustration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so as rgettman explained, I had to update my poi-ooxml-3.11.jar to poi-ooxml-3.17.jar, which can be done by just redownloading the binary source file and extracting the .zip file. After both were updated, I got another error, and this was fixed by adding the commons-collections4-4.1.jar and poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar. After adding these dependencies, my code ran. Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are to use **poi** jar and **poi-ooxml** jar, ensure they are same version.
2. You can also try out  **poi-ooxml** jar without **poi jar**.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has to be fixed by the apache team. In any way, the quick workaround as mentioned by @Fancypants753 is to make sure that the jars are of the same version. If any of them is different, definitely this issue would occur. I recently ran into it today and stumbled upon this SO question.

In my case, I have to downgrade from 5.2.0 to 4.1.2

Before, I was running these dependencies

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

But now, I was forced to downgrade to 4.1.2 to make sure all are of the same version, and because the latest version at this moment for poi-ooxml-schemas is 4.1.2, I cannot run a version higher than this for others.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the version displaying under the maven dependencies, and the pom.xml have the same version number.